# java android space in javacode/Id

Tags: java, android, xml

how do I use spaces or a space substitute in java?

xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/bus schedules"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

code that gives me errors

`findViewById(R.id.bus schedules)`

**edit**

I'm using.

```
int panelId = getResources().getIdentifier(Selection.toLowerCase(),
                "id,drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

So my `Selection` has to be the same as  `@+/id` or it will `return` `0` as in an invalid statement and my `Selection` is my display for the strings(string-array).

**Edit2**

Im using a `TextView`

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menufragment, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(SELECTION_NUMBER);
        String Selection = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Selection_array)[i];

        int panelId = getResources().getIdentifier(Selection.toLowerCase(),
                "id", getActivity().getPackageName());

        rootView.findViewById(panelId);


        getActivity().setTitle(drawerSelection);
        return rootView;
    }
```

`SELECTION_NUMBER` is from `selectItem(int position)` so it returns the position number shit above takes that number and finds the string in the `array` and tryes to match it to something in `R.java`

how does get to work

Comment: Use an underscore or camel-cased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have space while naming an ID.

The rule here apply is the same as the variable naming or filenaming rule. You can use _ (underscrore) for naming the ID.

Your ID must be start with an Alphabet and can be followed by number.

e.g. Valid ID

```
android:id="@+id/bus_schedules"
```

e.g. Invalid ID

```
android:id="@+id/bus schedules"
```

However there is one more method when you want to make readability in `bus schedules`. It is you may use Sentence Case like below,

```
android:id="@+id/BusSchedules"
```

Comment: so unless the Sentence Case will make java think there is a space in the word then its not going to work.

Comment: What you didnt understand ?

Comment: I don't understand what the "right" means in this context.


If I use `android:id="@+id/BusSchedules"` as my id it will put a space in the right spot and make 


    `int panelId = getResources().getIdentifier(Selection.toLowerCase(),
              "id,drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());` work?


And how that statement works is takes the selection from `Selection` as a string and look for it in `R.java` then `return` the `int` id given for that object so if it is not the same it will not find it as in `Selection = R.java string Id`

Comment: I mean this "so unless the Sentence Case will make java think there is a space in the word then its not going to work" is the right. You have to either use SentenceCase or UnderScore... Its basic Naming Convention rules.

Comment: I don't give a shit about basic naming rules. I'm asking how to get it to work. Either change the `[string-array]` to add some funky simbles that display a space or some black magic. Read edit2 for more information

Answer (score 0):

android Naming rules does not provide to allow for spaces while defining the id. I Recommended you to use **underscore(_)**.

```
android:id="@+id/bus schedules"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/bus_schedules"
```

Comment: no I can't unless I want my diplay for that string-array to have an underscore in it.